# Oracle Reference Partition migration to Postgresql

Tags: partitioning, migration, oracle-19c, postgresql-13

We are in process of migrating from Oracle 19c to Postgresql v13. We have a table in Oracle which has numerical primary key and is range partitioned based on a date column. This table has 3 child tables related via foreign key. These 3 tables have reference partition on the foreign key. Also these tables do not have the date column available in parent table.

While migrating these tables to postgresql, since reference partition is not supported in postgresql, one of the options is to

1. Add the same date column as in parent table to each of the 3 child tables.
2. One time script to populate this new column in each of the 3 child tables.
3. Changes in app to start populating this new column in each of the 3 child tables.
4. Update primary key of child tables to include this new date column
5. Range partition each of these 3 child tables using new date column.

Above approach is possible but requires a lot of changes. One other suggestion we have received is to replace the reference partition in child tables with hash partition in postgresql basis foreign  key. This looks promising as there are no breaking changes to be done in either DB or APP. But not sure if there is any other impact.

Could anyone please advise on what is the best approach for this migration?

Regards
Jacob